# Extract Specific Text from Html Page using htmlagilitypack

Tags: html

Hey most of my issue has been solved but i have little problem

This is Html

```
<tr>
<td class="ttl">&nbsp;
</td>
<td class="nfo">- MP4/H.263/H.264/WMV player<br />
- MP3/WAV/&#1077;AAC+/WMA player<br />
- Photo editor<br />
- Organizer<br />
- Voice command/dial<br />
- Flash Lite 3.0<br />
- T9</td>

</tr>
```

Currently i am using this code provided by Stackoverflow User

```
 var text1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='nfo']")[1].InnerHtml;
         textBox1.Text = text1;
```

know problem its is getting all text 
with `<br>`
how i can remove `<br>` from it and put , between them
its should look like this

```
MP4/H.263/H.264/WMV player,- MP3/WAV/еAAC+/WMA player,- Photo editor,- Organizer,- Voice command/dial,- Flash Lite 3.0,- T9
```

Also how to get this

```
<div id="ttl" class="brand">
<h1>Nokia C5-03</h1>
<p><a href="nokia-phones-1.php"><img src="http://img.gsmarena.com/vv/logos/lg_nokia.gif" alt="Nokia" /></a></p>
</div>
```

i am trying this

> var text41 =
>   htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div
>   id[@class='brand']")[0].InnerText;

i get invalid token error
 i only want C5-03 without nokia text

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract Specific Text from Html Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226173/extract-specific-text-from-html-page).  If you feel you have more information to add, please edit your previous question about this same topic, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle - different question, different issue.

Comment: +1 That's true, I don't know what I was thinking of there. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `string.Replace("<br />", "");` to remove the `<br />` tags.

Better yet, use the `InnerText` instead of `InnerHtml`, so no HTML comes through:

```
var text1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='nfo']")[1].InnerText;
```

If you really want to replace all `<br />` tags with a `,` you will indeed need to use `Replace`:

```
text1.Replace("<br />", ",");
```

---

To select the value in the `<H1>` tag, you could use:

```
var text42 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[id='ttl']"/h1)[0].InnerText;
```